# Will window.onhashchange detect anything other than navigation on a Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript

I've looked at the stackoverflow posts regarding the detection of navigation on a Single Page Application, and there are various solutions. One of them is to detect a path change (hash based paths) using `window.onhashchange`.

My question is this:

Is `window.onhashchange` used for anything else other than detecting a path change (hash based paths)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How does it works?

The [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) function is used for handling [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) events. From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange):

> The `hashchange` event is fired when the fragment identifier of the URL has changed (the part of the URL beginning with and following the `#` symbol).

So the `window.onhashchange` function is used to detect when the fragment identifier changes, nothing more, nothing less.

### Why/When should you use it?

You use `window.onhashchange` to detect when the fragment identifier changes, so the "When should I use `window.onhashchange`?" question is related to "When should I use fragment identifier?". The main usage of fragment identifier is to refer (link) to a specific part of a page, or how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) puts it:

> In computer hypertext, a **fragment identifier** is a string of characters that refers to a resource that is subordinate to another, primary resource. The primary resource is identified by a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), and the fragment identifier points to the subordinate resource.
>
> The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark `#` is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document. ...

It is also used to facilitate navigation in single page applications, and for various others reasons (storing state etc..). You can find quite comprehensive list of fragment identifier usages on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).